# Where to find Firebase Cloud Messaging API Key for Salesforce Push Notifications?

Tags: connected-apps, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, push-notification

Does anybody know where to get the API Key mentioned in [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_android_conn_app.htm) when using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

[image]

Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) has been replaced by FCM, and I'm not sure where to find the required API key.

I managed to send push notification directly from Firebase project to my app, but when I try to `send test notification` from my `Connected App` inside Salesforce I get an error message, probably due to incorrect API Key.

Comment: You simply need the Server Key. Via SO: Please see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37338923/617044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to https://console.firebase.google.com

You can find the Server Key and associated Sender ID in:

(gear-next-to-project-name) > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging

Comment: Thank you very much, this got me out of status quo finally. I copied the `Server Key` and tried to send the test notification again, and this time I got a new error message that I haven't seen before: `Recipient field contains registration ID that is not valid for the connected application's key for server applications (API key) (GCM error code: MismatchSenderId)`. Any chance you might know what's the issue?

Comment: When the registration call is made by our SDK it will return your SystemToken (search LogCat).  That is the token that you need to use.  Programmatically you can get it with the `getSystemToken()` convenience method and it will also be output from the `getSdkState()` method.

Comment: Thanks. I had to set the `androidPushNotificationClientId` in my **bootconfig.json** to `Sender ID` from Firebase. Now everything works perfectly.